# EOleException Error when trying to print a quick report

Tags: ms-access-2010, delphi-7

I have an Access database table named `Receipts` with the following field names: `receipt number` `item name`, `buying price`, `selling price`. I am using an Adoquery and datasource to connect to the access database. The following is the code I am using to print a report.

```
procedure TReceiptsform.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
qry :string;
begin
with ADOQuery1 do
         begin
         if ADOQuery1.Locate('receipt number',Edit1.Text,[]) then
      open;
      SQL.Clear;
qry:= 'SELECT*from Receipts WHERE (((Receipts.[receipt number])='+ edit1.Text+'))order by Receipts.[Item name]';
      SQL.Add(qry);
      Active:= True;
ReceiptForm.QuickRep1.Preview;
end;
end;
```

However when I run the program then I click `BitBtn1Click` at runtime, I get this error.

```
ProjectSales.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'Extra ) in query expression "(((Receipt.[item name])=))". Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.
```

Which exception handling code can I use to prevent this error or is there a problem with the Query?

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong (you have an extra `)` in your SQL statement) and where it is (around `((Receipts.[receipt number])=))`). That indicates that there is a problem in the query. A suggestion: Whenever you''re using things that have to be in pairs (like (), [] or {}), learn to count the number of opening symbols and the number of closing symbols; they should always be equal.

Comment: Read about SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

You problem is, that if Edit1 is *Null*, no value is given to filter on because the use of + eliminates the quotes:

```
'SELECT * from Receipts WHERE (((Receipts.[receipt number])='+ edit1.Text+'))order by Receipts.[Item name]'
```

=>

```
'SELECT * from Receipts WHERE (((Receipts.[receipt number])=)) order by Receipts.[Item name]'
```

So, use *ampersand* and some spaces:

```
'SELECT * from Receipts WHERE (((Receipts.[receipt number])=' & edit1.Text &')) order by Receipts.[Item name]'
```

Comment: When I run the program, I am getting these errors when I use ampersand `[Error] Receipts.pas(61): Illegal character in input file: '&' ($26)`, ` [Error] ReceiptRetrieve.pas(61): Statement expected, but expression of type 'String' found`

Comment: OK. Then you need to check for _no value_ of _edit1_ and, if so, run an SQL without the WHERE clause.

Comment: I strongly advise to not build your query like this, but use parameters. Not only will it solve any input from the user that causes errors in your select, not only will it make your code more readable, but it also takes care of sql injection which might be a serious problem here since you are taking input from a TextBox

Comment: @GuidoG Could you please write the code above using parameters or give me a link here where I can learn to use parameters in the code?

Comment: While that is a good idea, it won't solve your issue when trying to filter using _edit1_ having no value.